# Помогите разобраться с библиотекой распознавания лиц

Tags: node.js

Есть библиотека для NodeJs https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/tree/cfc96ba0af8c13d017d9c72f2c61ec968f1c15fb

Я разобрался как работает детект лица, но не могу понять как работает распознавание лиц.

Я хочу увидеть инструкцию, как создать базу с людьми, которых я хочу распознавать, а потом как их распознавать, я не имею ввиду нахождение лиц, я про различия лиц.

Comment: @virex-84 Я хочу увидеть инструкцию, как создать базу с людьми которых я хочу распознавать, а протом как их распознавать, я не имею ввиду нахождение лиц, я про различия лиц.

Comment: @Kromster Поправил